# How to add empty, non-selectable rows to a slickgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I'm using Slickgrid to display tabular data retrieved via JSON. The number of the grid items varies greatly (approx. 1 - 50 grid rows) and the grid is reloaded often with new data during the page lifecycle.

To make my grid less "jumpy" (i.e. to avoid frequent changes of the grid height), I'd like to display the grid with a constant height of 10 rows. If the JSON resultset is less than 10 items, the grid should be filled up with empty rows. If it is more than 10 rows, I want to activate paging.

I already figured out how to fill up the grid with empty rows, however I don't want these to be selectable or editable. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How did you fill it with empty rows? With empty data objects? This is the only way I know to do it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/slickgrid/1e8bub0drlw

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading it up with empty rows, why don't you just use a little bit of CSS?

```
div.slick-viewport {
    height: 100px; /* or whatever 10*row_height is */
}
```